# Java RMI Client cannot cast to exception

Tags: java, chat, rmi

I'm developing a RMI Chat System and I'm getting an exception running the client.
The exception I get is:

```
 Server failed: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1 cannot  be cast to rmi.ClientInterface
```

The line where the exception occurs is in my main class and it's the following:

```
 ClientInterface server =(ClientInterface) Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost/ABC");
```

Where ClientInterface is an interface that extends Remote.
Any idea how I can solve this?
Thanks

Comment: are you sure your server `ìmplements ClientInterface`. Should it not be something like `ServerInterface`?

Comment: Also try PortableRemoteObject.narrow(Object narrowFrom, Class narrowTo) instead of cast.

Comment: @regde That would only work if it was an RMI/IIOP remote object, which it isn't. And you still need to cast the result of `narrow()`.

Answer (score 0):

The usual cause for this is having two remote interface classes with the same name in different packages. It doesn't work. It has to be the same interface with the same content in the same package with the same name. Preferably the same object code.